# Vertically center popup modal with height set to auto

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal which is comprised to a series of list items obtained from an array, like so:

```
$.each(newsArr, function(i) {
  $('#allNewsDiv').append('<div class="all-news-item"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/r8nu1zb2gpzd92k/Ball%20Icon.png" alt="" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; position: relative; top: 2px;" width="20" height="20"><div class="all-news-item-text">' + newsArr[i] + '</div></div>');
});
```

The modal, which is originally hidden, can vary with the number of items in the array. I would like it to be centered vertically, but how do I do that when the height of the element can vary?

Thus far I have tried measuring the height of the div with `.outerHeight(true)` and setting the height of `#allNewsDiv` via jQuery's `.css` function. No luck! The height of each `.all-news-item` seems to be ignored and the height returned is simply the sum of the margins. The following CSS is used for the modal:

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #515151;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 99;
}

#allNewsDiv {
  width: 500px; 
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -275px;
  /*margin-top: ? */
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #000;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #000;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.all-news-item {
  font-family: 'Play';
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I have also tried using `transform: translate (50vw,50vh)` and `transform-origin: 50% 50%`, but, again, no luck!

Here is a fiddle (some of the styles have changed, but it's much the same):

https://jsfiddle.net/shaneswebdevelopment/1d6snzoq/

Comment: can u attach some Jsfiddle

Comment: it seems pretty centered to me

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi it seems that way because the sample isn't very exhaustive - it only has 4 items.  Update the fiddle to add 12 items and the dialog top is the same place as with 4 items but now the bottom goes off the bottom of the page.

Comment: you can use `flex` to make div vertical and horizontal center https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Adding a max-height would mean introducing a scrollbar and I'd like to avoid that at all costs, @freedomn-m

Comment: @Chilll007 that works well, but doesn't account for scrolling the `body` (i.e. it doesn't work with `position:fixed`). The modal needs to be centered in the window at all times.

Comment: Actually adding `height: 50vh` to the parent div seems to work!

Comment: `height` will work but it will show scroller if your inside content height is more than `50vh`.